# How to solve integral

Tags: calculus

How do I solve this integral?

$$\int\frac{x}{(3x+1)^2+1}\ dx$$

I have tried $u$-subtitution with

$u=3x+1$

$du=3 dx$

but then I get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, split the fraction:

$$\frac{x}{1+\left(1+3x\right)^2}=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\left\{\frac{1+3x}{1+\left(1+3x\right)^2}-\frac{1}{1+\left(1+3x\right)^2}\right\}\tag1$$

Substitute $\text{u}:=1+\left(1+3x\right)^2$, so we get:

$$\int\frac{1+3x}{1+\left(1+3x\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{6}\int\frac{1}{\text{u}}\space\text{d}\text{u}=\frac{\ln\left|\text{u}\right|}{6}+\text{C}_1=\frac{\ln\left|1+\left(1+3x\right)^2\right|}{6}+\text{C}_1\tag2$$

And substitute $\text{s}:=1+3x$, so we get:

$$\int\frac{1}{1+\left(1+3x\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{1+\text{s}^2}\space\text{d}\text{s}=\arctan\left(\text{s}\right)+\text{C}_2=\arctan\left(1+3x\right)+\text{C}_2\tag3$$

Comment: @egreg Look again at my answer!

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path! Start off with $u=3x+1$ so $du=3\, dx$. Therefore, we have$$I=\int\frac x{1+(3x+1)^2}\, dx=\frac 19\int\frac {u-1}{1+u^2}\, du$$Splitting up the integrand into separate fractions, we have$$I=\frac 19\int\frac {u\, du}{1+u^2}-\frac 19\int\frac {du}{1+u^2}$$
Can you continue from here? The answer is

> $$I=\frac 1{18}\left[\log(9x^2+6x+2)-2\arctan(3x+1)\right]+C$$

Answer (score 0):

ALGEBRA!

$$\frac{x}{(3x+1)^2+1}\equiv\frac{1}{3}\frac{3x}{(3x+1)^2+1}\equiv\frac{1}{3}\frac{3x+1-1}{(3x+1)^2+1}$$
$$\equiv\frac{1}{3}\frac{3x+1}{(3x+1)^2+1}-\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{(3x+1)^2+1}$$

The term on the left can be integrated either by eye or using the substitution you suggested. The term on the left is a standard $$\frac{1}{\text{Unfactorisable Quadratic}}$$
thing, which integrates to an $\arctan$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{x}{\left(3x+1\right)^2+1}dx$$
Let
$$:u=3x+1\implies x = \frac{u-1}{3} ,\quad dx = \frac{1}{3}\,du$$
Also
$$\int \frac{u-1}{9\left(u^2+1\right)}du$$
$$\frac{1}{9}\cdot \int \frac{u-1}{u^2+1}du$$
$$\frac{1}{9}\left(\int \frac{u}{u^2+1}du-\int \frac{1}{u^2+1}du\right)$$
$\int \frac{u}{u^2+1}du=\frac{1}{2}\ln \left|u^2+1\right|$
$\int \frac{1}{u^2+1}du=\arctan \left(u\right)$
$$\frac{1}{9}\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln \left|u^2+1\right|-\arctan \left(u\right)\right)$$
Substitute back $u=3x+1$

> $$\frac{1}{18}\left(\ln \left|9x^2+6x+2\right|-2\arctan \left(3x+1\right)\right)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Using your substitution:

$u = 3x+1$  , $du=3 dx$

Then $ \displaystyle\int\frac{x}{(3x+1)^2+1}\ dx = \frac{1}{3}\int \frac{\frac{u-1}{3}}{u^2+1}du= \frac{1}{9} \int \frac{u-1}{u^2+1}=\frac{1}{9} \int \frac{u}{u^2-1}- \frac{1}{9}\int \frac{1}{u^2+1}=\frac{1}{18}\ln|u^2-1|-\frac{1}{9}\arctan{u}+C$

Comment: and the substitute back $u=3x+1$ ?

Comment: I think that he can do it